# how to remove NA in character vector in R

Tags: r, na

How can I remove NAs in my dataset after ungrouping them in a character vector?

this is the **data set** :

```
Mno     drugs

100173  9
100173  3
100173   NA
100173   NA
100463  18
100463  18
100463  1
100463   NA
100463   NA
100463   NA
10061   18
10061   9
10061   2


a <- is.na(progression_diab)
```

I need the output like this:

```
s.no     Mno     drug3

1       100173      9
2       100173      3
5       100463      18
6       100463      18
7       100463      1
11      10061      18
12      10061      9
13      10061      2
14      10061      3
16      101793     0
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming `progression_dab` is a character vector, like `x` below, you can do:

```
x <- c("a", NA, "b")

na.omit(x)
## "a" "b"
```

or:

```
theNAs <- is.na(x) # the indices of the NAs
x[!theNAs] # remove theses indices to x
## "a" "b"
```